# Is it possible to create a firebase realtime DB dynamically from javascript and get its API keys?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a project of building a chrome extension and would want to create a Firebase Realtime DB dynamically on the fly, given that the user is already signed in Chrome and is ready to give all the required access permissions. Is it possible to do it programmatically from JavaScript? Is there a neat way out and if so what would be it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API to create Firebase projects, or a realtime database within an existing project. Creating projects or databases requires that the user signs in to the Firebase console.

But if you're trying to store data for users of *your* app, the common approach is to store that data in an existing database that *you* created.